# How to integrate Coinbase in Django

Tags: python, django, coinbase-api

I need to integrate Coinbase in Django to receive payments, but not Coinbase Commerce. I have been researching this and I think that with Coinbase Commerce, the normal one is not an option nowadays but anyway I would like to use it. Can I use Coinbase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you wouldn't want to use Coinbase Commerce for your app. I know it's not very straight forward like other django plugins but documentation is well written and simple to use. So to answer your question: No, You can't do that friend.
with Coinbase Commerce formal documentation and coinbase-commerece module for python, You can implement your payment method on your app.
And if you have a hard time to that, look at [this link](https://www.alextoussaint.com/2018-11-25_Integrate-Coinbase-Commerce-with-Django.html). It's really simple and short!